# Questions about C malloc function

Tags: c, memory-management, casting, malloc

Why do we cast `malloc`, as in the following?

```
ptd = (double *) malloc(max * sizeof(double));
```

What is `malloc`'s normal return type? Why do we *need* to cast it?

Comment: The return type is a `void *`. You don't *have* to cast it.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst So to confirm, I **SHOULDN'T** cast it? The above would just become `ptd = malloc(max * sizeof(double));`?

The author of this book casted it but has yet to explain exactly why. Why shouldn't it be cast? If it matters, `double *ptd` is where `ptd` is declared.

Comment: This is actually a question to you. Why really do you cast it? There's absolutely no reason to do it and it can actually be harmful. **Don't** cast the result of `malloc`. A good idiomatic form of `malloc` expression, applied to your example, would be `ptd = malloc(max * sizeof *ptd)`.

Comment: @AndreyT thanks, that looks good. So _never_ cast it?

Comment: Never cast it. Except in rare situations, a cast in C is an indication that you're doing something *wrong*. This is especially the case if the type you're casting from or to is a pointer type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a standard guide:

Declaration:

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

Allocates the requested memory and returns a pointer to it. 
The requested size is size bytes. 
The value of the space is indeterminate.
On success a pointer to the requested space is returned. 
On failure a null pointer is returned.

That should be everything!

Answer (score 0):

This is malloc prototype

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

Generally no need to do typecasting.